# upgrading wso2 api manager with custom url and https

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release

I am following this to upgrade WSO2 API-M 2.0.0 to 2.1.0.

My 2.0.0 API-M has custom url configured and https certificates configured to map the url.

If i follow the migration as in the document , Will these things gets automatically migrated? Or will i have to manaully change the url in all the configuration files and also do the changes for https ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to [1] which is configuring custom URLs per tenant. If so you do not have to redo these configuration in the registry since the new deployment will be pointing to the same registry database as given in the migration documentation.

The changes done to configuration files in the file system, has to be re done in the APIM 2.1.0 pack. You can do a diff of the file system and do those changes.

The SSL certificates also have to be imported again. As an alternative, you can copy the keystores and truststores to the APIM 2.1.0 from the older version instead.

[]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Customize+the+API+Store+and+Gateway+URLs

Comment: I am talking about custom url which wso2 is pointing. Like in carbon.xml and  in api-manager.xml ,custom url'are specified for updating the domain name.
Will those files automatically gets migrated?
Also what about ssl certificates?

Comment: No they won't get automatically migrated. You have to compare the files in APIM 2.0.0 and 2.1.0 and then do the same changes to 2.1.0 files. The SSL certificates also have to be imported again. As an alternative, you can copy the keystores and truststores to the APIM 2.1.0 from the older version instead.

Comment: So basically have to set up the new version altogether .Can you tell me what does apim200_to_apim210_gateway_artifact_migrator.sh And the parameter for -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity does?